# How to show a self-defined view as SCIM.app in the System preference - Keyboard - Input Sources

Tags: macos, preferences, ime

I am trying to intergrate our input method to the 10.10.3
And I found it's not easy to act like SCIM.app as the pic shows

I opened the activity monitor to see what file it opened (the SCIM.app was not running) As you can see in the following images:
  [image]
  [image]
The left shows the file list opened by System preference, and the right shows after I click the pinyin-chinese, the file list opened.
So I guess the little view was created by CoreChinese.framework.  Since it was in /System/Library/PrivateFramework , It seems impossible for me to show this view as SCIM.app by a normal way.
I turned to nm and hopper disassembler...But I found it a long way to go
I guess you guys may encounter the same question, maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I came across the same problems with yours.

1.It's easy to know that the view you saw, is provided by two part, the upper keyboard is a webview, which takes data in `/System/Library/Input Methods/SCIM.app/Contents/Resources/*.keylayout`, and finally shown by `IntlKeyboard.prePane` located in resources directory of `Keyboard.prePane`. and also you can find the actual html and pics, and 2nd part is a self-defined view provided by Preferences.prefPane.

2.Then 2nd part is to show the view you saw under the keyboard. as `SCIM.app` does, a file named `Preferences.prefPane`(must in the Resources directory of SCIM.app) was taken by IntlKeyboard.prePane.